# Adding ?> to a PHP comment

Tags: php, escaping, comments

I am fairly new to PHP and trying to create a piece of community learning code for my co-learners to help them and I want to put a coding tip in the comments. I tried writing the following:

```
# Tip -- when PHP is the only code in a file, don't put ?> at the end as this can cause bugs if white-space or additional PHP code is written to the end of the file after the file is initially created, after the ?>
```

However, typing `?>` in the comment ends the file and the comment. How do I escape this? I tried using `\` but that doesn't seem to work, and would also confuse the sense of the comment.

How is this done?

Comment: Try to use multi line comment like /*  */

Comment: I'll give it a shot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP doesn't work well with single lined comments using the closing and starting tags. Although you can use a muti-lined comment:

```
/* Tip -- when PHP is the only code in a file, don't put ?> at the end as this can cause bugs if white-space or additional PHP code is written to the end of the file after the file is initially created, after the ?> */
```

Note this is mentioned in the [*Comment Documentation for PHP*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php):

> The "one-line" comment styles only comment to the end of the line or the current block of PHP code, whichever comes first. This means that HTML code after // ... ?> or # ... ?> WILL be printed: ?> breaks out of PHP mode and returns to HTML mode, and // or # cannot influence that.